# JS - How to load new Vimeo video when the previous ends?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to know how can I load a new Vimeo video using Javascript.
I have my video IDs in an array, so I just need to put the ID there, when the first video finishes. I tried this code, but it doesnt seem to work for me:

```
    var array_position = 0;
    var options = {
        //first video id;
        id: array[array_position],
        width: 640,
        loop: false
    };

  var player = new Vimeo.Player('player', options);
  player.setVolume(50);

  player.on('ended', function() {
    //when ends array position will increment.
    array_position++;
    player.loadVideo(array[array_position]);
});
```

I also checked if the array position will really increment and it will. I just need to push the ID.
Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT: The code is now working.**

Comment: why not just use `new Vimeo.Player('player', options);` again instead of `loadVideo?

Comment: I just managed to fix that.

Comment: Maybe post your answer then for the next user.

Comment: The question is edited, containing the working code.